# Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

Best regards.

We raised our web project Compute Engine, and generally everything works fine, however we have a big problem with respect to communication.

The problem itself is that until we know for now, Google blocks ports 25, 465 and 587 to prevent abuse or misuse of these, but we believe that this is affecting our system of chat and messaging through our contact forms and subscription.

That is, when someone sends a message through one of our forms, or sign up with your email and other data to our newsletters, using also some form or when someone uses the chat (chat is own our) messages do not arrive.

The point is that we have tested this on other servers, and all works perfectly, we only have problems with Google Cloud service, however, we are very interested to use the instance of Google.

You know that thousands of websites work with Google Compute Engine, and chat and other systems operate perfectly, so there must be some way we can solve the problem.

We greatly appreciate if anyone can help us with ideas or concrete solutions. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you need to set up correct firewall rules to unblock the traffic on these ports, take a look at the documentation for details: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking

Answer (score 0):

Although standard email ports are blocked, you can choose a non-standard port to send email through and make sure to open the port in your GCE firewall. You can also take advantage of the mail services offered by Compute Engine partners.

SendGrid, Mailgun, and Mailjet are Compute Engine's third-party partners that offer a free tier for Compute Engine customers to set up and send email through their servers. If you don't have a Google Apps account, use these third-party partners to take advantage of features like click tracking, analytics, APIs, and other features to meet your email needs. More information can be found in this Help Center [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#sending_mail_through_corporate_mail_servers)